# How to stop Google Photos from trying to process .svg files as images

Tags: google-photos, synchronization

I have some .svg files created in Inkscape.

I don't want or need them to be converted/compressed for storage on Google Photos; just to be backed up.

How can I stop the `Can't add <x> files to Google Photos` message from appearing each time I sync?

Comment: Am I right in thinking this is not to do with Google Drive?

Comment: No. You are not. The problem is the .svg files are vector files, *not* raster files as Drive seems to think they are when it syncs my Drive folder. The files are only a few K in size and so don't *need *to be compressed at all. I just need them to be backed up WITHOUT Drive telling me each & every time that it couldn't compress them & so has stored them in their original format. Why warn me about this each time? Why not give you the option to ignore future messages for the same files in future? The message box displayed when it does this interferes with further syncs.

Comment: Google Drive doesn't compress files, but Google Photos can, which leads me to believe you're talking about Google Photos.

Comment: I've flagged this question to be migrated to [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com), since this is about Backup & Sync.

Comment: No, definitely not Photos. I'm talking about B&S, formerly Google Drive. Thanks for the escalation...!

Comment: Ivan, you are using Backup & Sync. It is not Google Drive, as Google Drive is a **web** application. You are most probably backing up photos to Google Photos using Backup & Sync. Google Drive does not compress anything. The problem you are talking about comes from Google Photos.

Comment: This question was bumped by Community user 12 times. I’m voting to close this question because it's about using obsolete and retired installable software. Google Drive for Desktop replaced it. A question about the current installable client to make file backups in Google Photos and Google Drive might be on-topic in [su] or [apple.se].

Answer (score 0):

In your Backup and Sync Preferences, you have this option checked: "Upload newly added photos and videos to Google Photos".

[image: Backup and Sync window]

The [official Google Photos help documentation for this](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103) says that the file types may only be .jpg, .gif, .webp, .tiff or .raw. That is the reason why you are getting the error message from Backup and Sync saying that you can't add .svg files to Google Photos.

With regards to the wording of your question, note that Google Drive (a web application) does not compress files. This question is about Backup and Sync, which is a computer application, hence why this question should be on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) rather than [webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). Also, note that the old name for Backup and Sync was not Google Drive, but rather *Drive for PC*. For these reasons, this question is not about Google Drive.

Comment: Sorry. I know they're different apps, but as the interact seamlessly, they've gradually merged into a single application in my mind! 

I'll repost the question to superuser.com as you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Does what I have said not give an answer?

Comment:  Indeed it does. But this then begs the question; why not just back up image files that it can't compress without telling me about it? Or, ideally, give you a check box to disable the message in the future?

Comment: Google Photos wouldn't be able to display those files. I agree that Backup and Sync shouldn't try to upload the files in the first place.

Comment: Well, if it didn't upload them, they'd not be backed up, no?

As I said above, I think it shouldn't try *compressing* image file types it doesn't understand and just back them up w/o complaining...

Comment: Short answer: it's impossible to back up a .svg file to Google Photos.